# number format for calculation

Tags: php

When 10000-100, then result should be 9900.

I tried when I use:-

```
< ?php

$num1 = number_format(round(10000,1),2);
$num2 = number_format(round(100,1),2);
echo $num1 - $num2;

?>
```

The above result is -90, that made me realize that the number_format function is not applicable in calculations.

Would there be any way that I can convert a value of number_format (obtained from POST from a previous page) back to numerical value for normal calculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start, the reason is that:

```
(int) "10,000.00"
```

resolves to 10 since it stops parsing at the first non-numeric character.  Thanks to PHP's weird type system, this is done implicitly when you subtract the strings.

Yes, you can strip out the commas easily:

```
$unformatted = str_replace(",", "", $formatted);
```

but it's cleaner to just post the raw numeric value (you can still use `number_format` for the displayed value).

EDIT: It is good practice to explicitly convert numeric strings (without commas) to float (or int) with either a cast (`(int)` or `(float)`) or the function version (`intval` or `floatval`).

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) for something like this? (I am assuming the posted value *could be* 1,950.50)

Comment: @Mischa, I agree that's good practice, though it alone doesn't address the issue.

Comment: Ah, I see.. I thought `floatval` could deal with commas, but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can perform this `10,000.00 -100.00` with the comma in the equation. Just perform the raw arithmetic operation ***then format the answer***.

```
$num1 = 10000;

$num2 = 100;

echo number_format(round($num1 - $num2,1),2);
```

This outputs

```
9,900.00
```

Comment: Note how it says "unexpected ','" (comma), not "unexpected '.'" (period) on the first, and stops parsing at the comma on the second.  Moreover, he's not subtracting literals.  He's subtracting formatted numeric strings, so neither of your examples are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way.

number_format is for fomating output numbers or to round easy numbers.
number_format gives us power to make well fomed rounded numbers, for a better user experience.
For calcualtion and saving Numbers in your MYSQL Database use this.

Save your Numbers in MYSQL always as type DECIMAL not FLOAT. There are lots of bugs if you want to calculate with FLOAT fields.

Than use the english notation.

```
$number = 1234.56; 
// english notation without thousands separator 
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', ''); //
//    1234.57
```

And now you can calculate and save it, without any Bugs.
Always Remember yourself, Saving numbers into $var is always a string.
Yeah, you can deifine type, but it doesn't matter in first case, and its to long to explain here.

For more information about number_format see here -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php